# How to obtain AD user credentials from computer with Apache, PHP and LDAP

Tags: php, apache, authentication, active-directory, ldap

We're trying to implement a single-sign-on solution that integrates AD and a PHP web application. When a user tries to access the intranet website, this is what should happen:

- The web app asks the server to read the AD credentials stored in the computer of a user already logged into windows/AD.
- AD "passes the AD username to Apache"
- Using PHP, I read the credentials stored -as I understand- in $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']

This is all meant to work only within an intranet. Outside it, We just display a login form.

We're somewhat stumped with this process. From [other](http://software.danielwatrous.com/access-apache-ldap-authentication-details-in-php/) [sources](http://cokeroman.blogspot.com/2011/02/autenticar-apache-contra-ldap.html), we configured Apache with the following directives, but were ultimately unsuccessful, with an internal server error message and nothing on the error logs.

```
<Location "/">
    Options -Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "VALIDAUTHNAME"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative   Off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://IP.FOR.THE.SERVER:389/DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=CL?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=MYCOUNTRY"
    Require ldap-attribute gidNumber=10000
</Location>
```

Is there a clear explanation of the process we have to implement? We've read lots of stuff about the inverse process, passing credentials to AD, but not much about this case. Our sysadmins aren't really experienced in this, so they aren't of much help.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without the user logging into the web app?  When you say "logged in user's windows account", is the user logged into Windows or logged into the web app?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to avoid presenting a login form for the web-app, and in fact logging the user in with his credentials, that's what I meant by single sign-on. I'm trying to log in to my app a user already logged into windows/AD, with the AD credentials stored in his computer. I tried to make it more clear in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago, I did exatly what you're trying to do with [`mod_auth_nltm_winbind`](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mod_auth_ntlm_winbind).  The configuration of it isn't very difficult, but it helps to be familiar with `winbind`.  Your sysadmins should be able to help with that if you aren't.  `winbind` is a part of the `samba` package, so it's probably already installed on your server.  Once you get winbind set up, you just need to enable the apache module and do a little bit of configuration.  The site for the module should be able to guide you through it.  When I originally set this up, I tested it with IE8, Chrome, and an older version of Firefox (5 or 6 maybe) and they all natively support the NTLM authentication.  If everything is configured and working correctly, the apache module will automagically fill `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` with the user name without needing any interaction with the user and you can do whatever you want to with it from there.  There is a lot more documentation available now and even with the lacking documentation before, I only had one major problem for which a fix is now well documented.